# Apply different XSLT after check the version from the xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working with two different xml version (3.2. and 3.3.)

XML Version 3.3 The version can be verify with the attibute cfdi:Comprobante/@Version

```
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd" LugarExpedicion="42084" MetodoPago="PUE" TipoDeComprobante="I" Total="28614.88" Moneda="MXN" Certificado="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" SubTotal="24668.00" NoCertificado="00001000000302655306" FormaPago="03" Sello="X/gOMJbMUDM0hA82um9ZYw09JMtPYs90U9ZqYHqYxLwOSoW66Aj3aIgQkzzvmD8O2JkTBJiAihQYW2tc9gL7IJEBQF+dnfO88ypX5b4ScOI57zMY1/pw8iyh5e7XRD3raLsgG0OnU9m53fvy68fbovxB+xYq8nPKhHbQZWgu9qc=" Fecha="2017-08-21T13:29:41" Folio="121" Serie="A" Version="3.3" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3">
  <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="rfc" Nombre="nombre" RegimenFiscal="621" />
  <cfdi:Receptor Rfc="rfc" Nombre="nombre" UsoCFDI="G03" />
  <cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="60122604" Cantidad="28" ClaveUnidad="EA" Unidad="pieza" Descripcion="descripcion" ValorUnitario="881.00" Importe="24668.00">
      <cfdi:Impuestos>
        <cfdi:Traslados>
          <cfdi:Traslado Base="24668.00" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="3946.88" />
        </cfdi:Traslados>
      </cfdi:Impuestos>
    </cfdi:Concepto>
  </cfdi:Conceptos>
  <cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="3946.88">
    <cfdi:Traslados>
      <cfdi:Traslado Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="3946.88" />
    </cfdi:Traslados>
  </cfdi:Impuestos>
  <cfdi:Complemento>
    <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigitalv11.xsd" Version="1.1" UUID="UUID" FechaTimbrado="2017-08-21T13:46:18" RfcProvCertif="SAT970701NN3" SelloCFD="X/gOMJbMUDM0hA82um9ZYw09JMtPYs90U9ZqYHqYxLwOSoW66Aj3aIgQkzzvmD8O2JkTBJiAihQYW2tc9gL7IJEBQF+dnfO88ypX5b4ScOI57zMY1/pw8iyh5e7XRD3raLsgG0OnU9m53fvy68fbovxB+xYq8nPKhHbQZWgu9qc=" NoCertificadoSAT="00001000000403258748" SelloSAT="C02d7c5PA4OBqpR0+qxjpQkdn4io1BTetRNqWEzvlAvhYvCNheZ9bGtQZYUyMu+cWvVIIRZ7zhcdjt+vZby6EYdF98Fz4l7OwIHVWV7fu0PRzU9uJRblJB9rMRe+ByZNFJ8HYswbsCIuNhjO1dND4VxMzwEIIaJGQ6iHQyMmHwGElx0z1KVBdnKVsADgcIudufoE9lQ11jGt71tfv1iG4XA3z/Ft8bkalb8uoemQi0/2aKquf3HbhDioUzj4fq+eyZEadsIQAOtrkylFSQIZNl8Unp3PkNW3S7K5dodRvebSlgB/X82geiMKlWFVnGCBFC6yA5naNDn4HEegcrQzMA==" />
  </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

XML Version 3.2. the version can be verify with the attribute cfdi:Comprobante/@version

```
<cfdi:Comprobante xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigital.xsd" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" version="3.2" serie="C" folio="7365" LugarExpedicion="ELIAS ZAMORA VERDUZCO 28 , LA CIMA, 28800, EL COLOMO, MANZANILLO, COLIMA, MEXICO" TipoCambio="1.00" Moneda="Peso Mexicano" fecha="2017-07-04T13:11:56" sello="lroX3cWHMDs/no3RbEixX4940jTwJHaeA3wv5XyNi9tjKXlo9g7lPd4PWkQwwL3lD/e2YSDiP96wVTceKqZZvZtYf8TbtrprlcPCEog9e7/vLG2Ywc+WhXLqbR1bOXnpz9/aiEElYyFeay7AYSMbizhlpMfV4cRJWtY3yN2OSsY=" formaDePago="PAGO EN UNA SOLA EXHIBICION" noCertificado="00001000000301323317" certificado="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" subTotal="52684.49" total="59154.01" metodoDePago="Transferencia Electronica" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <cfdi:Emisor rfc="rfc" nombre="nombre">
        <cfdi:DomicilioFiscal calle="ELIAS ZAMORA VERDUZCO" noExterior="28" colonia="LA CIMA" localidad="MANZANILLO" municipio="EL COLOMO" estado="COLIMA" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="cp" />
        <cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="REGIMEN GENERAL DE LEY PERSONAS MORALES" />
    </cfdi:Emisor>
    <cfdi:Receptor rfc="rfc" nombre="nombre">
        <cfdi:Domicilio calle="CIRCUITO  SAN FCO" noExterior="348" colonia="FRACC.RINCONADAS DE SAN FRANCISCO" localidad="HGO" municipio="MINERAL DE LA REFORMA" estado="HGO" pais="MEX" codigoPostal="cp" />
    </cfdi:Receptor>
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" unidad="No aplica" noIdentificacion="01" descripcion="FLETE" valorUnitario="49000.00" importe="49000.00" />
        <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" unidad="No aplica" noIdentificacion="02" descripcion="AUTOPISTAS&#xA;&#xA;2 X 40&quot; CONTS.NO. PCIU898114-5 / TCNU578696-3&#xA;&#xA;CON CARGA DE IMPORTACION&#xA;LIBRE DE MANIOBRAS PARA EL COND&#xA;FLETE POR COBRAR&#xA;PED.NO. 17 16 3724 7003271-0002&#xA;&#xA;OPERADOR. AARON CHAVEZ ARIAS&#xA;CHASIS. 072WR6 / 494UE6&#xA;&#xA;PESO. 23,068 KGS&#xA;&#xA;" valorUnitario="3684.49" importe="3684.49" />
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosRetenidos="1960.00" totalImpuestosTrasladados="8429.52">
        <cfdi:Retenciones>
            <cfdi:Retencion impuesto="IVA" importe="1960.00" />
        </cfdi:Retenciones>
        <cfdi:Traslados>
            <cfdi:Traslado impuesto="IVA" tasa="16.00" importe="8429.52" />
        </cfdi:Traslados>
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
    <cfdi:Complemento>
        <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigital.xsd" version="1.0" UUID="886759D7-DC88-47DE-9B0E-61AC83DBF684" FechaTimbrado="2017-07-04T13:12:03" selloCFD="lroX3cWHMDs/no3RbEixX4940jTwJHaeA3wv5XyNi9tjKXlo9g7lPd4PWkQwwL3lD/e2YSDiP96wVTceKqZZvZtYf8TbtrprlcPCEog9e7/vLG2Ywc+WhXLqbR1bOXnpz9/aiEElYyFeay7AYSMbizhlpMfV4cRJWtY3yN2OSsY=" noCertificadoSAT="00001000000404486074" selloSAT="b5vOGY/QY6nyjKe3T2JcexP7pCVOarfdGgcWEAJ9ySbO85SY1RglM4Q1VO8rCGwgapzN80/FbhB1413YK1RZ/Bo5xUUYD6h5DFFTzoH+ChuDhQ/Pb6pJRbntEkqAbfFMegKTccdrhxbLA3kpihEKadcnT/pXrfgnCrNcaT/GpSQ5pwJwWGZq73Qo/dw68yEgz50f3gJzxczij5HYgDJZ3ChrIjgxYG6Vo0RohVQoQPvuMdksOX9Pd6WjxVj5JTyWPHaLC8Yvpt2tAtSf7LOD0jOGTXqhR8kAVhc2L6CpaPhJYF1N/P3X73mLqFBar0bZ3R8+XKBzJR+hzXEv3/DEgQ==" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

The structure is the same but the attribute and nodes change, in the version 3.2. the nodes are in lowercase while in version 3.3. attributes and nodes start with uppercase

I'm trying to make a stylesheet xslt that check the version and select other stylesheet through the xsl:include function and apply the correct code

I need some like this

CheckVersion.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="cfdi:Comprobante">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@Version = '3.3'">
                <xsl:include href="version3.3.xsl"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@version = '3.2'">
                        <xsl:include href="version3.2.xsl"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>       
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then it's applied the xslt that correspond to the version

Which is my mistake or which is the correct code to my situation?, the xslt that check the version work but only with the version 3.2, when I apply this code with 3.3. the output show the "otherwise" from 3.2.xsl, when I need that select the 3.3.xsl

Outputs checkversion.xsl

version3.2.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigital.xsd" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="cfdi:Comprobante">               
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@tipoDeComprobante='ingreso'">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="//cfdi:Retenciones/cfdi:Retencion/@impuesto = 'ISR'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//cfdi:Emisor/@nombre"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="//cfdi:Retenciones/cfdi:Retencion/@impuesto = 'IVA'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//cfdi:Emisor/@rfc"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        Null
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>                                       
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                Null
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

version3.3.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigital.xsd" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>  
    <xsl:template match="cfdi:Comprobante">             
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@TipoDeComprobante = 'I'">
                <xsl:value-of select="//cfdi:Emisor/@Rfc"/>                                 
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                null
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both outputs work well if I apply the code directly to the xml

I apologize for my English,  the next time will be much better

Comment: You cannot conditionally include a stylesheet module via `xsl:include`, because `xsl:include` is required to be a top-level element in the stylesheet (that is, the parent element of an`xsl:include` must be the `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` element, whichever you are using).

Comment: You can use a single stylesheet with two sets of templates in two different *modes*. Or, if the only difference is the case, use templates that match both - e.g. `<xsl:template match="@Rfc | @rfc">`.

Comment: Thanks, but the situation is that the 3.3 version uses catalogs that standardized the capture by a third party, while the 3.2 version is very simply (does not add catalogs). I need to separate the code for each xml version also because the 3.2 version the next year will not be used and the examples that I show in the outputs are not the final result.

I need worked independently with each version to ease its use and expand the possibilities to the program.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to writing a stylesheet that has to handle two similar vocabularies is to do a 2-phase transformation: phase 1 normalizes the document by translating one vocabulary into the other, phase 2 does the actual transformation. The great advantage of this approach is reuse: you don't end up duplicating code. There's a slight performance penalty, but it shouldn't hurt unless things are really critical.

Another approach is to generate two stylesheets from a common master. Because XSLT is XML, it's particularly well suited to code-generation techniques.

If you do want to stick with the logic "if version="x" then apply transformation T else apply transformation U", then I would probably do this logic outside XSLT. Consider a pipeline language such as XProc or Ant.